# What's the difference between "boast of" and " boast about"?

Tags: prepositions

What's the difference between "boast of" and " boast about" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the most part, the two prepositions can be used interchangeably. According to [The Free Dictonary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/boast+about), "boast of" and "boast about" are practically the same idiom. For example, both of these are valid,

> The chef boasts of his restaurant having the most authentic Italian food in all of New York City.
>
> The chef boasts about his restaurant having the most authentic Italian food in all of New York City.

A common thing with *boast* is that adjectives are commonly placed between the verb and the proposition. For instance,

> He always boasts highly of/about himself.
>
> They never boast highly of/about the unsung heroes.

Again, not much difference between *of* and *about* here. One last comment is that if you choose not to use a preposition with *boast*, then the verb can take on a whole new meaning. For *boast* has two meanings according to [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/boast),

> 1) to speak too proudly or show too much satisfaction about something or someone connected with you
>
> 2) to have or possess something to be proud of

The earlier sentences addressed the first definition, but now the second definition can be addressed.

> Harvard boasts high expectations for its students.
>
> The coach boasts high hopes for his championship-caliber team.

However, *boast* alone can still take on the first definition like it did with a preposition.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Can I use reflexive pronoun after boast as in the following sentence - "He was boasting himself".

Comment: @Sunny you could say something like "He was boasting himself a genius". However I believe that this sounds awkward so I would just say "He was boasting of himself" or "He was boasting of himself as a genius".

Answer (score 0):

To me, things boasted of may or may not be founded whereas things boasted about are generally true.

See [example sentences of both](http://www.manythings.org/sentences/words/boast/1.html) here.

But the better question is, is boasting ever called for?

http://www.cbsnews.com/news/money-and-manners-are-you-offensive/

https://mkueber001.wordpress.com/2014/11/18/is-it-bad-manners-to-brag-about-your-kids/

Don't know. Will let you draw your own conclusions.